# Display Fixed background opengl 2 on Android

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

I am developing an opengl application with cardboard of google (opengl 2). I have to set a fixed background but i haven't found any tutorial where is explained to obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

load background texture during initialization

then during rendering after `glClear`; disable writing to depth buffer (`glDepthMask(false);`) and render a full screen quad with the texture and then reenable writing to the depth buffer